# Docker Wrong Time

Tags: docker, datetime

I am in the process of setting up a system in Docker where extensions are being added to the current system. Here the system is complaining that they were created in the future.

Since the whole system is based on Java I set the java timezone variable to Europe/Berlin in the docker file when building the image. Because this still didn't fix the bug I had the system time displayed via the LocalDateTime.now() and this tells me it is 2020-01-28T22:13:23.421 and not 2020-02-05T17:06. So I am offset for whole days.

On another system the error also occurs with 2h 35 min offset.

Now my question is: Can I synchronize the time in Docker and if so how.

As a base image I use bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine:8.
Docker runs on Windows 10 pro.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a time zone issue.  Is the *host* time synchronized?  In Windows, the "Set time automatically" option enabled in the date & time settings page?

Comment: Also, a Google search shows lots of discussion about Docker for Windows being out of time sync after a sleep/resume of the host.  Is that the case here?